# C++ storing raw character array in tuple

Tags: c++, tuples, variadic-templates, c-strings

Why can't I assign character arrays in `std::pair` or `boost::tuple`?

```
typedef std::pair<int, char [5]> tuple_type;
tuple_type(5, "abcd");
```

The above produces the following error.

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::pair<int, char [5]>::pair(int, const char [5])’
   51 |     tuple_type(5, "abcd");
```

Even if I use `std::pair<int, const char [5]>` the error persists

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::pair<int, const char [5]>::pair(int, const char [5])’
```

The only solution is to either use `const char*` or `std::string` But in my actual problem I am packing a set of variadic arguments into a tuple.

```
template <typename Ret, typename CallableT, typename... Args>
struct returned_: public Ret{
    typedef boost::hana::tuple<Args...> tuple_type;
    tuple_type _tuple;
    const CallableT& _call;

    returned_(const CallableT& call, const Args&... args): _call(call), _tuple(args...), Ret(_tuple){}
    // ...
};
```

So unless the usercode casts into `const char*` or wraps inside `std::string` the template `returned_` will yield compile time errors. What is the solution without forcing the user not to pass C string literal ?

Comment: Would `boost::hana::tuple<std::decay_t<Args>...>` work for you?

Comment: You can use typestring library to pass string literals as arrays of chars https://github.com/irrequietus/typestring

Comment: @NathanOliver No, possibly because it is converting to `char*` instead of converting to `const char*` I am getting error `error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::hana::tuple<int, char*>::tuple(const int&, const char [6])’`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have mentioned in the question I don't want to force the user to pass only `std::string` or cast to `const char*`. I am going in the direction pointed by @NathanOliver

```
template <typename T>
struct trans{
    typedef typename std::decay<T>::type type;
};
template <int N>
struct trans<char[N]>{
    typedef const char* type;
};

template <typename T>
using trans_t = typename trans<T>::type;
```

The above template will transform `char[N]` to `const char*`.

```
template <typename Ret, typename CallableT, typename... Args>
struct returned_: public Ret{
    typedef boost::hana::tuple<trans_t<Args>...> tuple_type; // trans_t will convert char[N] to const char*
    tuple_type _tuple;
    const CallableT& _call;

    returned_(const CallableT& call, const Args&... args): _call(call), _tuple(args...), Ret(_tuple){}
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 3):

In the argument list expressions

```
tuple_type(5, "abcd");
```

the string literal `"abcd"` is implicitly converted to the type `const char *`. And arrays do not have the assignment operator and moreover when a pointer is used as an initializer.

Answer (score 0):

C-array are not copiable, you might want to wrap it into a struct as `std::array` which is copiable.